# When exactly is System.ArgumentException thrown?

Tags: c#, .net, object, exception, methods

Imagine the following error:

```
SomeObject.someMethod failed with System.ArgumentException: Requested value 'someArgument' was not found.
```

Does that mean the situation is this:

```
new SomeObject().someMethod(invalid arguments);
```

or this:

```
public class SomeObject
{
    public SomeObject() { }
    public void someMethod(Argument someArgument) { someOtherMethod(invalid arguments); }
    private void someOtherMethod(Argument someArgument) { /*do something*/ }
}
```

Normally, I would just manually generate this exception in the debugger but if I hardcode it to happen then it just won't compile, and I have no idea what the end user is doing to cause this exception.  But I can see it happening in the event logs.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Documentation of [ArgumentException Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception(v=vs.110).aspx) states: The exception that is thrown when one of the arguments provided to a method is not valid.

Comment: If it is from an official Microsoft method, then you can check the MSDN article on the method. In the specific example you gave at the top, it sounds like a poorly worded replacement for an `ArgumentNullException`.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The exception that is thrown when one of the arguments provided to a
>   method is not valid.

For instance, let that we have the following class

```
public class Account
{
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    public Account(decimal amount)
    {
        Amount = amount;
    }

    public decimal CalculateTax(decimal taxAmount)
    {
        if(taxAmount>0.8*Amount)
            throw new ArgumentException("The taxAmount should be less than 80% of Amount", "percentage");

        return Amount-taxAmount;
    }
}
```

Let now that we create an `Account` object:

```
var account = new Account(1000M);
```

If we call the `CalculateTax` passing as a `taxAmount` 900M, then an `ArgumentException` would be thrown.

Comment: Your example should instead be throwing an [ArgumentOutOfRangeException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentoutofrangeexception(v=vs.110).aspx) (as stated in the documentation for `ArgumentException`).

Comment: @crashmstr I corrected it. Do you think that the example now is more suitable?